# Ruby: Using a string variable to call an array element set is not working

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, hash

I'm trying to call a set of elements in the example below.

```
session_times: {
    thursday: ["10:20am", "12:30pm", "6:40pm"],
    friday: ["10:20am", "12:30pm", "6:40pm"],
    saturday: ["10:20am", "12:30pm", "6:00pm"],
    sunday: ["10:20am", "12:30pm", "6:30pm"]
  }
```

I tried doing the following functions

```
days_all = movie[:session_times]
string = ':' + 'thursday'
var1 = days_all[:thursday]
var2 = days_all["#{string}"]
var3 = days_all[string]
```

The variable var1 comes out perfectly fine but i dont understand why var2 or var 3 will not get my result, it should come out the same with same variable called right?

Help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is a difference between symbol and string and they are not always interchangable. A symbol is not the same as a string starting with a colon (that's still a string). When you use the `key: val` hash syntax the keys are symbols; `"key" => val` would be a string key.

any of these would work:

```
string = "thursday" # don't put the colon in here
days_all[:"#{string}"]
days_all[string.to_sym]
days_all["#{string}".to_sym]
```

If you install the gem `activesupport` and then `require active_support/all` (this is automatically done in rails), it's less strict about what key you need to use:

```
days_all = days_all.with_indifferent_access
days_all["thursday"]
days_all[:thursday]
days_all.thursday
```

Comment: Thanks that did it :)
Sorry for late reply

Answer (score 1):

With Ruby `:x` refers to a Symbol and `"x"` refers to a string. A Symbol is an "internalized string", it acts more like an arbitrary constant, and every instance of `:x` is identical with every other, they're literally the same object.

The same is not true for strings, each one may be different, and normally occupies a different chunk of memory. This is why you see Symbols used for keys in hashes, their repetition would be wasteful otherwise.

You can reference your structure any of the following ways:

```
days_all[:thursday] # With a plain symbol
days_all["thursday".to_sym] # With a converted string
days_all[:"thursday"] # With a long-form symbol
```

Another thing to note is you probably don't want to stick with this data structure if you can avoid it. This isn't very "machine readable", names like `:thursday` are completely arbitrary. It's much better to use a consistent index like `0` meaning Sunday, `1` meaning Monday and so on. That way functions like [`cwday`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-cwday) can be used to look things up in a regular Array.

The same goes for human-annotated times like `"10:30pm"` where a value like `1350` meaning 22 hours plus 30 minutes, or even `2230` if you don't mind gaps between your intervals. Those are easy to compare: `1130<230` is never suddenly true due to ASCII sorting issues.